# JQuery option selected event for html select element?

Tags: jquery, html

Well, I have pretty common scenario: do some stuff when html select option is **selected**. There are tons of similar questions and the answer always is to use `change` event. Just like here in this my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLTED/) example. This works fine, BUT... The problem is I want to `do stuff` even when the same option is selected again. Not when the option is changed but when it is **selected**! For example in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xLTED/) actual example - when document is ready, empty option is selected. When I select empty option, in this case, I will not see the alert because `select` was actually not changed. But I need to see that alert. I'm just curious is there some `select` event or (if not) what is the proper way to implement such behavior?

I could do something like:

```
$('select.my-select option').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

But it does nothing. I don't get expected behavior. I tried:
**Opera 19.0.1326.63**
**IE 11.0.9600.16518**
**Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m**
**Firefox 27.0.1**

also I tried this code in older browsers, such as Opera 12, and it worked perfectly. But it doesn't work in browsers listed above.

Comment: What do you need to execute when the user selects the same option? You're previously executed could should still stand true.

Comment: @tymeJV, I want to alert selected option value every time option was selected, clicked, I guess.

Comment: $('select.my-select').click - you are not clicking on the options

Comment: @matpol, I use `$('select.my-select option').click` to click option.

Comment: This will work in FF, IE, Opera, but not in chrome,Safari.. looks like webket issue.

Comment: why don't you try mousedown event ?

Comment: @Sridhar, I tried, just like click (option), it does nothing.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi change that last example in your question. I solved that with my answer. With you want more, provide more information.

Comment: you don't click the option you click the select(dropdown) - you might want try onchange rather than onclick

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
$('select.my-select').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: It has absolutely the same behavior as in [my exmple](http://jsfiddle.net/xLTED/)

Comment: It works, yes, but it doesn't work when you select `1` option (in my case it is `empty` option) just after document is ready (when it is already selected). You don't get alert. And I need this alert. The second jsfeedle alerts every time I click on `select` but not when I select it's option.

Comment: this is weird. everytime i choose an option i get an alert. even when i choose the empty option

Comment: what you said doesn't make sense. because selecting an option triggers the click event on the select event which in turn triggers the defined callback function

Comment: I'm afraid I just can't explain properly what I want to achieve. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLTED/) is my example again. Try to select empty option. Just when document is ready. Select empty option. Alert will not be shown because change event is not firing since select was not changed. It was empty and when you selected empty - it didn't change. So change event is not acceptable for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47686/discussion-between-anurupr-and-dmytro-tsiniavskyi)

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/h67nh/3/)

It implements what I understand you want, it handle a first selection, that is done by default.

Basically you do a search for the default selection, before the user had really selected one:

```
$('.my-select option').each(function() {
    var text = $( ".my-select option:selected" ).text();        
    if (this.selected){      
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

Then, any option could be your default, since you add the `selected` attribute:

```
<option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
```

**EDIT:** Note that you show use either `selected` or `selected="selected"`, altough it is boolean, saying `selected=true` is wrong.

Comment: Nope, it's not what I want to achieve.... I think I should provide more detailed explanation...

Comment: It handles the `Not when the option is changed but when it is selected`  argument. For example the first option, which was not selected by the user, but was selected by the program.

Comment: Tell me what I wrote does, and then tell me the differences from what you want, what it should do.